# Website access with cached Windows credentials

Tags: windows, active-directory, authorization, credentials

I am working at a company which uses an intranet site as a portal to a bunch of other local sites. Unauthorized people in the company have been accessing it, so we want to secure it. Users, when accessing the website for the first time will have to enter a username and password. If they are on a certain group in the Active Directory, they will be given access and their credentials will be stored so that they don't need to enter their username/password again. I have looked into NTML, ASP.NET, but am not sure how to proceed.

Any thoughts/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many individual are going to be accessing this site also who on your end will be setting up the AD-UserGroups..? this is very easy to do via Web / Windows you have to make sure you are coding this based on the users login. for example on a web page ..everytime the Page_Load event gets fired you would want to check the uses acess level if you have a MasterPage(s) you can do it there as well ..then you could set up a Switch basically enabling or disabling menu items or other page controls based on their Group setting from AD

Answer (score 0):

Dump your solution. Use Integrated Windows Authentication, namely Kerberos, in IIS. It will automatically pass all credenentials to your server. Note that every participant *must* be part of your AD domain.